# ggseasonplot for hourly data with weekly seasonality equivalent

Tags: r

I have a time series with one hour resolution, that displays weekly seasonality. I'm looking for an equivalent of the function `ggseasonplot` from the `ggplot2` package that works for weekly seasonality.

I have looked online but haven't found any similar function, except for the `seasonplot`, which is the same as `ggseasonplot` but less fancy.

```
data<-read.csv("series.csv") 
hours <- seq(ISOdatetime(2016,4,18,0,0,0), ISOdatetime(2016,5,22,23,0,0), by=(60*60))
time_series<- xts::xts(data[123118:123957,2],hours)
time_series168 <- ts(data,frequency = 168)

ggseasonplot(time_series168,continuous = TRUE)
```

[image: R plot]

I'd like to have weeks instead of year on the plot. And on the plot each hour of the week is a season, I'd like the "seasons" to be days.

Sample of my data:

```
Datetime            series
2016-04-18 00:00:00 4124
2016-04-18 01:00:00 3932
2016-04-18 02:00:00 3823
2016-04-18 03:00:00 3830
2016-04-18 04:00:00 3797
2016-04-18 05:00:00 3935
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution so I'm posting it in case someone else is looking for this:

```
plot(1:168,time_series168[1:168],type="l",xaxt = "n",col=rgb(0,0.2,1),xlab="Days of week",ylab="Time series",main="Evolution of time series over the weeks",lwd=1.5)

for(i in 1:4){
   color<-rgb(0.25*i,0.2,1-0.2*i)
   left<-168*i+1
   right<-168*(i+1)
   lines(1:168,time_series168[left:right],type="l",xaxt = "n", col=color, lwd=1.5)
} 

axis(1, at=c(24,48,72,96,120,144,168)-12, labels=c("Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"))
legend("topright",bty="n",legend=c("into the past","into the future"), col=c(rgb(0,0.2,1), rgb(1,0.2,0.2)), lty=1,lwd=2)
```

By setting `xaxt = "n"` the axis are unlabelled, then one can label them with `labels` in `axis`.